# "Bean class com.xxx.domain.Customer is not enhanced?" error in gradle/kotlin app

Tags: gradle, orm, kotlin, ebean

I'm trying to use Ebean in a Kotlin app with Gradle.

I have followed many examples on GitHub and I'm pretty sure my code is OK but I keep receiving this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bean class com.xxx.domain.Customer is not enhanced?
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.setEntityBeanClass(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1413)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.createByteCode(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1285)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1207)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:710)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:325)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:141)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:130)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:79)
 at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:44)
 at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:55)
 at io.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.getWithCreate(Ebean.java:201)
 at io.ebean.Ebean$ServerManager.<init>(Ebean.java:159)
 ... 6 more
```

Here is my build.gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath "io.ebean:ebean-gradle-plugin:10.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'ebean'


mainClassName = 'com.xxx.HelloWorldKt'


defaultTasks 'run'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    kapt "io.ebean:kotlin-querybean-generator:10.1.2"

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    compile "io.ebean:ebean:10.3.1"
    compile "io.ebean:ebean-querybean:10.3.1"

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}


kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}


sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main")]
}
```

I have installed 2 plugins in IntelliJ.

- Ebean 10.x Enhancement
- Ebean enhancement

Both are activated.

Here is my Bean code

```
import io.ebean.Model
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Customer : Model() {

    @Id
    var id: Long = 0

    var name: String = ""

    var version: Long = 0
}
```

I have tried running the app using the "App configuration" and the "Gradle configuration". Both do the same errors.

I can see that the QCustomer generated code is there but I keep receiving this error all the time.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was 4 things to check for this problem:

1) Since I've done multiple test with the same code, my "build" folder was full of previously generated code and "Rebuild" function did not clean it up. I did a delete myself + full "rebuild" and it removed a lot of error message. But something else was missing.

2) Make sure your file "ebean.mf" in the "resource" folder is has the right "entity-packages" and "transactional-packages". In my case it was `com.xxx.domain`. This is the folder that needs enhancements and contains your models.

3) If you are using an "application" configuration settings (starting the application with the IDE), make sure to install and activate the right Ebean Enhancement plugin. In my case, I only needed the Ebean 10.x Enhancement plugin.

4) If you are using a "gradle" configuration settings make sure the sourceSets is set like that:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main")]
}
```

Hope that help. I spent so much time on this.